# HSQL postgres dialog not recognized

Tags: integration-testing, hsqldb, in-memory-database, hypersql

I want to use HSQL for integration tests. Therefore I want to setup the test schema with exact the same script I use for production. This is in postgresql dialect. In the test script I tried to set the dialect but it doesn't seem to work.

At least for uuid datatype and constraints I get syntax error exceptions. E.g. I get a:

> CREATE TABLE testtable ( id bigint NOT NULL, some_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
>   name character varying(32) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT testtable PRIMARY KEY
>   (id) ) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE ); nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks
>   privilege: UUID

for the following script:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;

CREATE TABLE testtable
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  some_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
  name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT testtable PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

And I get:

> Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource
>   [setupTestData.sql]: CREATE TABLE testtable ( id bigint NOT NULL, name
>   character varying(32) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT testtable PRIMARY KEY (id)
>   ) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE ); nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (

for this script:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;

CREATE TABLE testtable
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  --some_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
  name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT testtable PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB 2.3.4 and later supports UUID.

HSQLDB does not currently support the PostgreSQL extension `WITH (ODS= FALSE)`